# ftp4j - Too many connections exception

Tags: android, ftp4j

I am creating a sync service which will copy files to ftp folder selected by user. When i run the service, it connects with ftp and check whether file at android local storage is available at ftp or not and if not, it uploads. Below is my code.

```
   FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.setPassive(true);



            if (!ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            }else {
                Log.i(TAG,"FTP already connected");
            }
            if (!ftpClient.isAuthenticated()) {
                ftpClient.login(username, password);
            }else {
                Log.i(TAG,"FTP already Logged In");
            }

            ftpClient.changeDirectory(rfolderpath);
            String[] files = ftpClient.listNames();

            if (Arrays.asList(files).contains(filename)) {
                Log.i(TAG, filename + " Already Found in FTP, Skipping");

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Sending Go Ahead For Upload");
                File file = new File(filepath);
                Log.i(TAG, "Uploading File: " + filename);
                ftpClient.upload(file);
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect(true);
            }
```

The code works fine for first 8 files and then i start getting exception of too many connections (8) from this IP and my sync terminates.

Here is Error text:

```
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException [code=421, message= Too many connections (8) from this IP]
```

Can someone help me how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic of uploading files. Now created one ftp connection under AsyncTaskLoader and with that upload all files w/o error.